# How does lazy-seq accumulate the result?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lazy-sequences

Here is the [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/r1.10.339-24-g0773689e/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L5203-L5223) of `partition` function in clojurescript. The other methods are removed for simplicity.

I have hard time understanding how the `lazy-seq` accumulates the result. At the end there is a `when` which if I understand correctly will return `nil` if the test is false. Where does that `nil` go in the next iteration of `lazy-seq`?

```
(defn partition
  "Returns a lazy sequence of lists of n items each, at offsets step
  apart. If step is not supplied, defaults to n, i.e. the partitions
  do not overlap. If a pad collection is supplied, use its elements as
  necessary to complete last partition up to n items. In case there are
  not enough padding elements, return a partition with less than n items."
  ;; ...
  ([n step coll]
     (lazy-seq
       (when-let [s (seq coll)]
         (let [p (take n s)]
           (when (== n (count p))
             (cons p (partition n step (drop step s))))))))
  ;; ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Special Interpretation of `nil`

`cons` is a special form (i.e. it is not a function, but a compiler built-in).  `cons` knows that a `nil` means "no more data is coming".

```
(cons 7 nil)   => (7)
(cons 7 '())   => (7)
(cons 7  [])   => [7]
```

So, if either `when-let` or `when` fails, `nil` is returned and we have something like `(cons 7 nil)`. Therefore, the lazy sequence is terminated (the `nil` is discarded), and at this point it is equivalent to a plain list.

---

### Returning `nil`

Your question surprised me!  I hadn't thought it would work, but here is the code:

```
(defn odd->nil [it]
  (if (odd? it)
    nil
    it))

(defn down-from
  "Count down from N to 1"
  [n]
  (lazy-seq
    (when (pos? n)
      (cons (odd->nil n) (down-from (dec n))))))

(down-from 5) => (nil 4 nil 2 nil)
```

So we see there is a big difference between `nil` being the first or 2nd argument to `cons`. If `nil` is the first arg, it is added to the beginning of the list as normal.  If `nil` is the second arg, it is (silently) converted into an empty list, and the result is a 1-element list:

```
(cons nil [99])  => (nil 99)   ; works like normal
(cons  99  nil)  => (99)       ; creates a 1-elem list
(cons nil  nil)  => (nil)      ; for completeness
```

---

### P.S.

Note there is a slight contradiction with `seq`, since we have:

```
(seq nil) => nil
```

---

### P.P.S  `rest` vs `next`

I never use `next`, since I don't like silent conversions to `nil`:

```
(next [1]) => nil
(next [])  => nil
(next nil) => nil
```

I prefer to use `rest`, since it will give me an empty list as I expect:

```
(rest [1]) => ()
(rest [])  => ()
(rest nil) => ()
```

I can then write a test like so:

```
  (let [remaining (rest some-seq) ]
    (when-not (empty remaining)      ; says what it means
       ....more processing.... ))
```

I don't like assumptions about silent conversions:

```
(when (next some-seq)        ; silently converts [] => nil
  ....more processing.... )  ; & relies on nil <=> false
```

---

### One Last Thing

You may be interested in a small refinement called `lazy-cons` [described here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#simplified-lazy-sequence-generation).  I think it is a bit simpler than the original `lazy-seq`.

```
(defn lazy-countdown [n]
  (when (<= 0 n)
    (lazy-cons n (lazy-countdown (dec n)))))

(deftest t-all
  (is= (lazy-countdown  5) [5 4 3 2 1 0] )
  (is= (lazy-countdown  1) [1 0] )
  (is= (lazy-countdown  0) [0] )
  (is= (lazy-countdown -1) nil ))
```

It also has [a cousin the emulates Python-style generator functions](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#generator-functions-for-lazy-sequences-a-la-python).

Comment: True `(cons nil '(1)) ;; => (nil 1)` and `(cons 1 nil) ;; => (1)`.